# if en ajax no funciona para deshabilitar botón

Tags: ajax, condiciones

tengo que ajax que lo que hace es corroborar si un artículo exite o no al escribir en u input
Es funciona todo bien, el problema lo tengo al querer hacer que si no está libre, digamos disponible, el boton de agregar artículo quede deshabilitado

Mi código es el siguiente

```
function buscar_duplicado_art() {
  bt_art.disabled = true;
  var duplicado_art = {
    articulo: $("#art_id_div").val(),
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "ajax_duplicado_articulo.php",
    data: duplicado_art,
    success: function (r) {
      if ($("#art_id_div").val().length > 0) {
        $("#control_art_duplicado").html(r);
        if (r == "Libre") {
          console.log(r);
          bt_art.disabled = false;
        } else {
          bt_art.disabled = true;
        }
      } else {
        $("#control_art_duplicado").html();
      }
    },
  });

  return false;
}
```

Cuando hago un consol.log(r) la respuesta es correcta. Devuelve "Libre" u "Ocupado" según si ya existe o no en la base de dato

El boton enviar esta bien tambien creo

```
<button id="bt_art" name="submit" value="" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%">Agregar</button>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme
gracias

Comment: Donde estas asignando bt_art? Ya que lo llamas directamente por que no lo declaras dentro de la función. Te arroja algún error por consola?

Comment: No me da error por consola. Ya lo he solucionado. Edito la pregunta por si a alguien le sirve y aparte para aportar la solución. Muchas gracias

Comment: NO NO.. no edites la pregunta.. hay un lugar que dice respuesta, y las respuestas van EXPLICADAS en el campo respuesta.. vos pusiste un monton de codigo sin explicar porque eso es la respuesta. Explica el problema y la solucion, en el campo respuesta

Comment: Gracias por explicarme y perdón por no saber sobre la norma del foro. Ya lo he realizado. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude resolver. Aparentemente el problema que estaba teniendo era que pasaba una variable de texto desde el PHP y no la podía resolver con el IF en javascript

Al cambiar el texto por numero ya lo tomó bien

Dejo el código

```
function buscar_duplicado_art() {
  document.getElementById('bt_art').disabled=true;
  var duplicado_art = {
    articulo: $("#art_id_div").val(),
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "ajax_duplicado_articulo.php",
    data: duplicado_art,
    success: function (r) {
      if ($("#art_id_div").val().length > 0) {

        if (r == 0){
          document.getElementById('bt_art').disabled=false;
          $("#control_art_duplicado").html('<i class="bi bi-check-circle-fill fs-6 text-warning"></i>');
  
        } else {
          document.getElementById('bt_art').disabled=true;
          $("#control_art_duplicado").html('<i class="bi bi-x-octagon-fill fs-6 text-danger"></i>');
        }
        
      } else {
        $("#control_art_duplicado").html();
        
      }
    },
  });

  return false;
}
```